# Map Standard Field with Custom Field - Lead Conversion

Tags: process-builder

I have a look-up field (Contact) on the Opportunity Layout (which it is a required field) and I would like to map it to the first name and last name of the Lead, so through lead conversion the look-up field gets populated.

I have created a Process Builder, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing anything?

Please see below:

Lead - when a record is created or edited.

- Lead is converted - conditions are met

  - [Lead.Is converted] = True
- Record - [Lead].Coverted Opportunity ID  - no criteria - just update the records.
- Contact - Formula - [lead].firstname & & [lead].lastname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to update a lookup field (`Opportunity.Contact__c`) you need to set the field value to be an ID of the Contact, not the first and last name.

This can be found in `Lead.ConvertedContactId`.

Note the lead conversion process will create a junction record between Opportunity and Lead called OpportunityContactRole which might also serve your application purposes rather than a lookup from Opportunity to Contact.

Comment: Thank you. It perfectly worked in Sandbox, but when I have deployed it to Production, it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @SSimion Hmmm. Check permissions to the custom field for the Prod running user vs sandbox running user.  The Prod debug log may help too

Comment: Checked the permissions to the custom field for Prod and Sandbox. I even checked the debug log for Prod. Still looking into it. Thanks a lot for your help.